# Identity involving q-Pochhammer symbols -- "Normalization"

Tags: combinatorics, induction, binomial-coefficients, q-series, pochhammer-symbol

I am trying to prove the following identity involving q-Pochhammer symbols
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{n} \dfrac{1}{(c^{-1};c^{-1})_m (c;c)_{n-m}}=1$$
where $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $(a;q)_n=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1-aq^i) $ denotes the q-Pochhammer symbol. I tried to run a few simulations for different values of $n$ and $c$ and I always got $1$, but I did not manage to prove it by using the induction principle and other identities.
I think that the proof of this relation could give some insight to compute the other following summation
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{n} \dfrac{c^{-mk}}{(c^{-1};c^{-1})_m (c;c)_{n-m}}$$
where $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Many thanks in advance to anyone having some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange the summands and apply the q-binomial theorem:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{1}{(q^{-1};q^{-1})_m (q,q)_{n-m}}
&=
    \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{(-1)^mq^{\frac{m(m+1)}{2}}}{(q;q)_m(q;q)_{n-m}}
=\frac{(q;q)_n}{(q;q)_n}=1.
\end{align*}